# How can I find the lowest integer a large power number is congruent with?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Ok so in an exercise I have I'm supposed to calculate $73^{1567}\mod(990)$
What the solution suggest is first divide $990$ into relative primes: $9\cdot11\cdot2\cdot5$.

Then comes the next step which seriously confuses me because we are supposed to find the lowest whole number for each of the relative primes for which $73^{1567}$ is congruent with. How am I supposed to do this?

 I have asked my teacher and her explanation was that if 73 is congruent with $1\mod2$ then so is when we take both to the power of 1567, but this method doesn't work when the number isn't 1.

So how would I solve this question? It's supposed to end with using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: the solution should be $127$

Comment: Yes that I know, I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293606/how-to-calculate-the-power-modulo-990-without-a-calculator

Comment: I bet it's the same course, the professor is really really bad and all the material can hardly be read cause her handwriting is terrible...

Answer (score 1):

You need [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), which you can find referenced on this site many times.  It says for $p$ prime and $a$ coprime to $p, a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$  To compute $73^{1567} \pmod {11}$ we note that $73^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {11},$ so $73^{1567} \equiv 73^7 \pmod {11}\equiv 7^7 \pmod {11}$ and you can evaluate that by squaring and reducing $\bmod 11$ at each step.  Do the same for all the other primes dividing $990$ and reassemble your results using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: How does this work with 9, since it's not prime?

Comment: @HugoLewenhaupt There is an immediate generalisation of Fermat's little, called Euler's theorem. It allows any modulus, not just primes (as long as the base of the exponent and the modulus are coprime), and it says that the relevant exponent, instead of $p-1$, is $\phi(p)$ (which happens to be $p-1$ when $p$ is prime) where $\phi$ is the [Euler totient function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). In our case, we get $a^6\equiv1\pmod9$ for all $a$ not divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=73^{1567}$. Obviously, $a\equiv1\pmod 2$. Also $73\equiv1\pmod 9$
so $a\equiv1\pmod 9$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem $a\equiv1\pmod {18}$.

What about $5$? Well, $73\equiv3$, $73^2\equiv3^2\equiv4$ and
$73^4\equiv 4^2\equiv1\pmod 5$. So $73^{4n}\equiv1\pmod 5$. In particular
$73^{1564}\equiv1\pmod 5$ and $a\equiv 73^{1564}73^{3}\equiv3^3\equiv2\pmod5$.

There's also $11$. By Little Fermat, $73^{10}\equiv1\pmod{11}$,
so $a\equiv 73^7\equiv 7^7\equiv6\pmod{11}$ if I've done my sums right.

We have $a\equiv1\pmod{18}$, $a\equiv2\pmod{5}$,  $a\equiv6\pmod{11}$.
We can now use CRT to get a $b$ between $1$ and $990$ with $a\equiv b\pmod{990}$.

Comment: How do you know that a is congruent to 73^7?

Comment: @HugoLewenhaupt Because $73^{1560}\equiv1\pmod{11}$

Comment: Alright so reusing the 4n part.,